# Filling null values with mean in PDI (PENTAHO)

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have a xls input file and extracted mean using "Univariate Statistics" step; I tried to use "If field value is null" but I didn't figure out to replace the null values by mean from "Univariate Statistics". Can anyone help me with this?
I am using Pentaho 8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let do it with sample way:
Step1: calculate mean of value.
Step2: Add mean to main stream.
Step3: Replace null by mean value by Java Script (Script Value Step).
Here is my transform:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before execute mean operation using "Univariate Statistics", you can remove NULL values from input data using below steps (way)
[image]

And if you really want to replace NULL value with any other value, you can use "If field value null" step in following way of configuration.

[image]
Here I replace NULL value with '1'

Let me know if you want anything else.